# Terraform and ansible - forward keys

Tags: terraform

I need to use the forward agent option. I have in tf

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = <<-EOT
  cd ../systems/ac/ansible/
  ansible-playbook playbooks/install/ac/playbooks/preinstall.yml  --inventory=../../ansible/ansible-local-environment/inventory/${var.domain}/${var.system}.${var.domain}
```

Where I clone a git repo, but I get access denied.

When i launch a playbook locally - the repository is cloned correctly because the keys are correctly displayed in ssh-add -l

```
ssh-add -l
3072 SHA256:4RjItcuYK0WoCvSZsSmSDUsoYwuo+/M859066Y3d/E8 knex@local.ac.d (RSA)
3072 SHA256:gCZ+VTwFnOaLnYk9N+LNkDBzfcokQm4VG6+l/qzHxZg knex@Mac-knex.local (RSA)
```

and I have correct ~/.ssh/config

```
Host *.ac.example.eu
  User knex
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

my ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
interpreter_python = auto_silent
transform_invalid_group_chars = always
deprecation_warnings = false
roles_path = ./ansible-roles
host_key_checking = False
sudo_flags=-HE
ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
pipelining=True
```

But when I run a playbook from terraform - terraform ignore ssh-add -l
I get

```
"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."
```

Is there any way around this? I have to forward these keys

When I start the playbook myself - everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I added in local-exec ssh-add -k and now work.